# Knockout Text Effect Background Disappears Depending On Positioning Of Text?

Tags: html, css

I am using `-webkit-background-clip` to create a knockout text effect in addition to using `background-attachment` set as `fixed` so when the user scrolls the background of the text moves

```
section > h2{
    background-image: linear-gradient( to right bottom, rgba( 107, 187, 219, .7), rgba( 37, 149, 195, .7 ) ), url( '../images/background.jpg' );
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
     -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    //margin: 40px 0 0 80px;
    font-size: 72px;
     font-weight: 900;
     margin-bottom: 60px;
     font-family: "Avenir";
     text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

The issue I am having is that depending upon the placement of the text, like if I float the H2 to the right, nothing shows up. I can highlight the text, but the background does not show.

Here is the text positioned on the page and as I resize the browser window the background starts to dissapear, but this only happens when the `background-attachment` property is set to `fixed`

[image]

Comment: share full code so we can reproduce the issue

Answer (score 1):

Do you have tried with using ***position: relative;*** to the main div and ***position: absolute;*** to your text then, translate it to make it responsive and don't interfere with other objects in position absolute?

An Example:

```
.maindiv{
 position: relative;
}

h1#myid {
 position: absolute;
 top: 20%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -20%);
}
```

I hope I helped you,

Greetings,

Squarety.

Comment: Hey thanks for the input, I did some more research and there isn't a ton of info on it, but it looks like there is a bug with webkit based browsers, I think Chrome in particular, that dates back to 2014 that still has not been fixed. There is a bug with the placement of a fixed background on an element and using translate. Really odd it's never been fixed.